# Conclude the premise using rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

First question I have solved I belive... show, s -> (q -> r) <-> (s ^ q) -> r using the defintion of implication and Boolean algebra.

s ->(~q V r)   <-> ~ (s ^ q ) V r 
~s V (~q V r ) <-> ~s V ~q V r 
~s V ~q V r <-> ~s V ~q V r

L.H.S = R.H.S

Second question I'm having troubles with inference... given the premises: 
(1) p -> (q -> r), 
(2) p V ~ s, 
(3) q Show that you can
conclude s -> r, using the rules of inference and the result in part above.

How should I go about the second question? I'm slightly confused when it comes to inference rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the result in part one, you need to go two steps further: You need to show that what you started with: $s \rightarrow (q\rightarrow r)$ is equivalent to $(s \land q)\rightarrow r.$ I'll start where you leave off:

$$\begin{align} (\lnot s \lor \lnot q \lor r) & \iff (\lnot(s \land q) \lor r)\tag{DeMorgan's} \\ \\ & \iff ((s \land q) \rightarrow r)\tag{implication}\end{align}$$

For the second question: Please double check your premises, as typed here, with the original problem statement. If you can use the result above, then you can use the result $p \rightarrow(q \rightarrow r) \equiv (p \land q) \rightarrow r$.

Now, with the added premise:

List the premises.

Start of subproof:
Assume $s\equiv \lnot(\lnot s)$.

Infer that this implies $p$ by the second premise.

Conjoin ($\land$ "and") the just derived $p$ with premise three $q$ to get $(p \land q)$.

Use the first premise, along with the result from the first part (the statement equivalent to the first premise) to conclude $r$.

End of subproof.

Therefore $s \implies r$.

You can also prove the desired implication without the result from the first part of your question.

Comment: Sorry dumb question, but how do I check my premises?

Comment: What I mean is take a look back at the question as stated in your text or exercise sheet to ensure you typed it in correctly: in particular, the variables used, and any possible premise missing from your posted question.

Comment: I caught the typo! (3) q Show that you can
conclude s -> r, using the rules of inference and the result in part (a) above. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: "Infer that this implies p by the second premise." -- I'm having troubles grasping this, any way you can break it down? thanks

Comment: @amWhy: This needs something to go with the check +1 :-)